# Adding different layers/labels to OSM Stamen map with QGIS

Tags: openstreetmap, qgis, stamen-maps

I am using the OSM OpenLayers plugin to use OSM Stamen (toner lite) basemap for a project I am doing on central London.

I'd really like to add neighbourhood names from OSM as the only significantly visible location names are some large streets (e.g. Pall Mall, Baker Street, etc.) and what I'd like is to include neighbourhood/area names like 'Mayfair', 'Shoreditch', 'The City' and so on.

Is there an easy way to add this information to the map? I know it must be in the OSM data as a layer somewhere (the normal default OSM basemap has the neighbourhoods named), so is it easy to let it come through onto my Stamen basemap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer I have personally come to after reading up further is that it is not possible to customise or alter the OSM Stamen basemap in this way, and I would suggest people facing this issue instead do manual annotations on your map, or use an alternative source for OSM that somehow allows editing of the layers that are drawn from the OSM API.